# How to prevent terminal colours dim / change when ConEmu loses focus?

Tags: windows, conemu

When ConEmu loses focus it goes from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I've been unable to find any relevant focus settings. How can I prevent this behaviour?

`ConEmu 161206 [64] {Stable}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should disable the `Fade when inactive` option on `Features -> Colors` tab of the Settings.

[image]